# How to optimize structure of the tables?

Tags: postgresql-13

Database

- PostgreSQL 13.10

Structure

[image]

Constraints

- name is "filter_test_group_id_test_group_id_test_name_id_filter_key_uniq"

  - `UNIQUE(id_test_group, id_test_name, id_filter, key)`

Indexes

- name is "filter_test_group_index_id_test"

  - `CREATE INDEX filter_test_group_index_id_test ON filter_test_group(id_test_group)`

Details

- for most cases(~90%) the `key` column contains SHA1 hash
- for some cases(~10%) the `key` column contains simple strings like 'filter1', 'filter2', ...

Query

```
INSERT INTO management.filter_test_group
   (id_test_group, id_test_name, id_filter, key, value)
VALUES
   ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}')
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT filter_test_group_id_test_group_id_test_name_id_filter_key_uniq
DO UPDATE SET value = '{4}'
```

Usage

- I have many upserts for the `value` column based on the unique constraint
- I do several upserts for unique constraints in a single transaction(ReadCommitted)
- All upserts in a transaction belog to different unique constraints

Problem

- The upsert query run slowly as the size of the table grows

Question

- Who may I optimaze the structure of the tables or optimaze the way how to update the `value` column?

It is possible to leave only SHA1 hash for the `key` column if it will help

Comment: "*The upsert query run slowly as the size of the table grows*" - What does the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE ` show?

Comment: It shows "Insert on filter_test_group as filter_test_group (rows=0 loops=1)" even for existence rows, looks like it works enough fast and an issue in other part of implementation. @J.D. thanks for the advice